# Fread function giving same value

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

Hello every one I want to ask question about fread and fwrite function

i have called the fread function like this

```
 fread(&buf , sizeof(short int) ,1 ,f1);
```

and also like this

```
 fread(&buf , 1, sizeof(short int) ,f1);
```

similarly fwrite both are working correctly.why ? which is actually right ?and which to use?
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct. The second may result in reading just a partial short.

The second parameter is record size and the third is the number of records. `fread` will read an integer number of records, but may read fewer than the requested number of records (for instance, if `EOF` is encountered).